# Replace word and characters in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm in the midst of figuring out the RegExp function capabilities and trying to create this string:

```
api/seaarch/redirect/complete/127879/2013-11-27/4-12-2013/7/2/0/0/LGW/null
```

from this:

```
/api/search/redirect/complete/127879/2013-11-27/4-12-2013/7/2/0/0/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/^^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined/undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined/undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined/undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined^undefined/LGW/null
```

I know `\bundefined\b\^` removes 'undefined^' and `undefined\b\/` removes 'undefined/' but how do i combine these together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, since the `^` or `/` follow the `undefined` in the same place, you can use a character class:

```
str = str.replace(/\bundefined[/^]+/g, '');
```

Note: `^` is special both inside and outside of character classes, but in different ways. *Inside* a character class (`[...]`), it's only special if it's the first character, hence my not making it the first char above.

Also note the `+` at the end, saying "one *or more*" of the `^` or `/`. Without that, since there are a couple of double `^^`, you end up with `^` in the result.

If you want to be a bit paranoid (and I admit I probably would be), you could escape the `/` within the character class. For me it works if you don't, with Chrome's implementation, but trying to follow the pattern definition in the spec is...tiresome...so I honestly don't know if there's any implementation out there that would try to end the expression as of the `/` in the character class. So with the escape:

```
str = str.replace(/\bundefined[\/^]+/g, '');
```

Comment: It's not just `^`, it's `\^`, which is escaped, so a literal `^`

Comment: @beerbajay: (You mean in the question.) Thanks, I somehow misssed that.